# Define default values for function arguments

Tags: function, lua

In the Lua wiki I found a way to define default values for missing arguments:

```
function myfunction(a,b,c)
    b = b or 7
    c = c or 5
    print (a,b,c)
end
```

Is that the only way? The PHP style `myfunction (a,b=7,c=5)` does not seem to work. Not that the Lua way doesn't work, I am just wondering if this is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If you want named arguments and default values like PHP or Python, you can call your function with a table constructor:

```
myfunction{a,b=3,c=2}
```

(This is seen in many places in Lua, such as [the advanced forms of LuaSocket's protocol modules](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html) and constructors in [IUPLua](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/).)

The function itself could have a signature like this:

```
function myfunction(t)
    setmetatable(t,{__index={b=7, c=5}})
    local a, b, c =
      t[1] or t.a, 
      t[2] or t.b,
      t[3] or t.c
    -- function continues down here...
end
```

Any values missing from the table of parameters will be taken from the `__index` table in its metatable (see [the documentation on metatables](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8)).

Of course, more advanced parameter styles are possible using table constructors and functions- you can write whatever you need. For example, [here](https://gist.github.com/975399) is a function that constructs a function that takes named-or-positional argument tables from a table defining the parameter names and default values and a function taking a regular argument list.

As a non-language-level feature, such calls can be changed to provide new behaviors and semantics:

- Variables could be made to accept more than one name
- Positional variables and keyword variables can be interspersed - and defining both can give precedence to either (or cause an error)
- Keyword-only positionless variables can be made, as well as nameless position-only ones
- The fairly-verbose table construction could be done by parsing a string
- The argument list could be used verbatim if the function is called with something other than 1 table

Some useful functions for writing argument translators are `unpack` (moving to `table.unpack` in 5.2), `setfenv` (deprecated in 5.2 with the new `_ENV` construction), and `select` (which returns a single value from a given argument list, or the length of the list with `'#'`).

Comment: A I just started using lua I will keep it simple for the time but your post is very informative. Might come handy later on. Thanks.

Comment: In most cases, keeping it simple is the way to go. Meta-parameter interfaces are only really necessary for objects with a large number of optional attributes (such as UI objects).

Comment: I think this answer is the one who solves the questions, not the one currently marked as accepted. Thanks for the enlightenment :)

Comment: It should be noted that the `x or default` expression also used in this reply is not really a true equivalent to parameter defaults but just a simplistic workaround that only works if both `nil` and `false` are invalid parameter values. Let's say the default for a boolean parameter `x` is `true` and the caller passes an explicit `false`. Then `x or true` gives `true`, even though `false` was explicitly passed. A better version would be `if x == nil then x = default end`, which is also more readable; it still can't handle explicit `nil` arguments though.

Comment: Oh, hey, this is the accepted answer now! Nice. (For the record, and to put @Undo's comment in context, jpjacobs's answer below was the accepted answer for a very long time: I nearly got [a second Populist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/populist?userid=34799) over it.)

Comment: so this answer creates 2 tables on the heap for every call, modifies its input (what if t has a metatable already?), and it doesn't work with boolean args. how is this a good answer?

Comment: @capr If your function's on a hot-enough path for two ≤two-item table allocations to cause a noticeable performance hit, you shouldn't be providing a sugared calling interface for it in the first place. Figure out the right memoization / factorization pattern for your use case, set `local` variables outside the hot loops, and use the binding for the most-iterated segment. (Besides, unless you're JITting it, I suspect the function call overhead's more likely to be more of a performance hit anyway.)

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley you suspect wrong, malloc is far slower than a function call (not to mention the garbage collection overhead). The only thing that would help here is the allocation sinking optimization of LJ2.1.

Answer (score 54):

In my opinion there isn't another way. That's just the Lua mentality: no frills, and except for some syntactic sugar, no redundant ways of doing simple things.

Comment: This answer is completely disproven by Stuart P. Bentley's answer below, in which the function is called with a table constructor.  This is one of the strengths of Lua:  while it doesn't have a bunch of frills, the fundamental building blocks of Lua allow you to do limitless things, truly remarkable for the small size and simplicity of the language.

Comment: @ColinDBennett Thanks for speaking up: it would appear the OP read your comment and, that December, changed the accepted answer accordingly. (And now it's "Stuart P. Bentley's answer above", for clarity's sake :wink:)

Comment: this is the correct answer but the real reason is that args are passed on a stack in Lua and so calling `f(a=1)` would require a check for the position of arg `a` _on every call to `f`_ which would be far more expensive than calling `f` with positional args only. If Lua were a static language in which this information would be static and known at compile-time, named args would have no runtime cost and would probably be a feature by now.

Answer (score 25):

Technically, there's `b = b == nil and 7 or b` (which should be used in the case where `false` is a valid value as `false or 7` evaluates to 7), but that's probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: If you're not checking for `false`, a simpler way is to put the variable first and the default last. `b = b or 7`

Comment: Since the OP mentioned that in their question, I figured it would be superfluous to mention (the question was about ways to define default variables *other than* `b = b or 7`).

Answer (score 10):

The only way i've found so far that makes any sense is to do something like this:

```
function new(params)
  params = params or {}
  options = {
    name = "Object name"
  }

  for k,v in pairs(params) do options[k] = v end

  some_var = options.name
end

new({ name = "test" })
new()
```

Answer (score 8):

As always, "Lua gives you the power, you build the mechanisms". The first distinction to make here is that between *named parameters* and the commonly used *parameter list*.

## The parameter list

Assuming all your args are given in the parameter list as follows, they will all be initialized. At this point, you can't distinguish between "wasn't passed" and "was passed as `nil`" - both will simply be `nil`. Your options for setting defaults are:

1. Using the `or` operator if you expect a truthy value (not `nil` or `false`). Defaulting to something even if `false` is given might be a feature in this case.
2. Using an explicit `nil` check `param == nil`, used either as `if param == nil then param = default end` or the typical Lua ternary construct `param == nil and default or param`.

If you find yourself frequently repeating the patterns from point (2), you might want to declare a function:

```lua
function default(value, default_value)
    if value == nil then return default_value end
    return value
end
```

(whether to use global or local scope for this function is another issue I won't get into here).

I've included all three ways the following example:

```lua
function f(x, y, z, w)
    x = x or 1
    y = y == nil and 2 or y
    if z == nil then z = 3 end
    w = default(w, 4)
    print(x, y, z, w)
end
f()
f(1)
f(1, 2)
f(1, 2, 3)
f(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

note that this also allows omitting arguments inbetween; trailing `nil` arguments will also be treated as absent:

```lua
f(nil)
f(nil, 2, 3)
f(nil, 2, nil, 4)
f(1, 2, 3, nil)
```

### Varargs

A lesser known feature of Lua is the ability to actually determine how many arguments were passed, including the ability to distinguish between explicitly passed `nil` arguments and "no argument" through the [`select`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-select) function. Let's rewrite our function using this:

```lua
function f(...)
    local n_args = select("#", ...) -- number of arguments passed
    local x, y, z, w = ...
    if n_args < 4 then w = 4 end
    if n_args < 3 then z = 3 end
    if n_args < 2 then y = 2 end
    if n_args < 1 then x = 1 end
    print(x, y, z, w)
end
f() -- prints "1 2 3 4"
f(nil) -- prints "nil 2 3 4"
f(1, nil) -- prints "1 nil 3 4"
f(1, nil, 3) -- prints "1 nil 3 4"
f(nil, nil, nil, nil) -- prints 4x nil
```

Caveat: (1) the argument list got dragged into the function, hurting readability (2) this is rather cumbersome to write manually, and should probably be abstracted away, perhaps time using a *wrapper function* `wrap_defaults({1, 2, 3, 4}, f)` that supplies the defaults as appropriate. Implementation of this is left up to the reader as an exercise (hint: the straightforward way would first collect the args into a garbage table, then unpack that after setting the defaults).

## Table calls

Lua provides syntactic sugar for calling functions with a single table as the only argument: `f{...}` is equivalent to `f({...})`. Furthermore, `{f(...)}` can be used to capture a vararg returned by `f` (caveat: if `f` returns `nil`s, the table will have holes in it's list part).

Tables also allow implementing *named "arguments"* as table fields: Tables allow mixing a list and a hash part, making `f{1, named_arg = 2}` perfectly valid Lua.

In terms of limitations, the **advantage of table call is that it only leaves a single argument - the table - on the stack rather than multiple arguments**. For recursive functions, this allows hitting the stack overflow later. Since PUC Lua drastically increased the stack limit to ~1M this isn't much of an issue anymore; LuaJIT still has a stack limit of ~65k however, and PUC Lua 5.1 is even lower at around 15k.

**In terms of performance & memory consumption, the table call is obviously worse: It requires Lua to build a garbage table, which will then waste memory until the GC gets rid of it.** Garbage parameter tables should therefore probably not be used in hotspots where plenty of calls happen. Indexing a hashmap is also obviously slower than getting values straight off the stack.

That said, let's examine the ways to implement defaults for tables:

### Unpacking / Destructuring

[`unpack`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-unpack) (`table.unpack` in later versions (5.2+)) can be used to convert a table into a vararg, which can be treated like a parameter list; note however that in Lua the list part can't have trailing `nil` values, not allowing you to distinguish "no value" and `nil`. Unpacking / destructuring to locals also helps performance since it gets rid of repeated table indexing.

```lua
function f(params)
    local x, y, z, w = unpack(params)
    -- use same code as if x, y, z, w were regular params
end
f{1, 2, nil}
```

if you use named fields, you'll have to explicitly destructure those:

```lua
function f(params)
    local x, y, z, w = params.x, params.y, params.z, params.w
    -- use same code as if x, y, z, w were regular params
end
f{x = 1, w = 4}
```

mix & match is possible:

```lua
function f(params)
    local x, y, z = unpack(params)
    local w = params.w
    -- use same code as if x, y, z, w were regular params
end
f{1, 2, w = 4}
```

### Metatables

The `__index` metatable field can be used to set a table which is indexed with `name` if `params.name` is `nil`, providing defaults for `nil` values. One major drawback of setting a metatable on a passed table is that the passed table's metatable *will be lost*, perhaps leading to unexpected behavior on the caller's end. You could use `getmetatable` and `setmetatable` to restore the metatable after you're done operating with the `params`, but that would be rather dirty, hence I would recommend against it.

#### Bad

```lua
function f(params)
    setmetatable(params, {__index = {x = 1, y = 2, z = 3, w = 4}})
    -- use params.[xyzw], possibly unpacking / destructuring
end
f{x = 1}
```

in addition to the presumably garbage params table, this will create (1) a garbage metatable and (2) a garbage default table *every time the function is called*. This is pretty bad. Since the metatable is constant, simply drag it out of the function, making it an upvalue:

#### Okay

```lua
local defaults_metatable = {__index = {x = 1, y = 2, z = 3, w = 4}}
function f(params)
    setmetatable(params, defaults_metatable)
    -- use params.[xyzw], possibly unpacking / destructuring
end
```

### Avoiding metatables

If you want a default table without the hackyness of metatables, consider once again writing yourself a helper function to complete a table with default values:

```lua
local function complete(params, defaults)
    for param, default in pairs(defaults) do
        if params[param] == nil then
            params[param] = default
        end
    end
end
```

this will change the `params` table, properly setting the defaults; use as `params = complete(params, defaults)`. Again, remember to drag the `defaults` table out of the function.

Comment: I think `z == 3` in the second code block should be `z = 3` but SO won't let me make a one-character edit and I'm not well-versed in the subject enough to otherwise contribute meaningfully to the answer

Answer (score 3):

If your function expects neither Boolean `false` nor `nil` to be passed as parameter values, your suggested approach is fine:

```lua
function test1(param)
  local default = 10
  param = param or default
  return param
end

--[[
test1(): [10]
test1(nil): [10]
test1(true): [true]
test1(false): [10]
]]
```

If your function allows Boolean `false`, but not `nil`, to be passed as the parameter value, you can check for the presence of `nil`, as suggested by [Stuart P. Bentley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023147/111948), as long as the default value is not Boolean `false`:

```lua
function test2(param)
  local default = 10
  param = (param == nil and default) or param
  return param
end

--[[
test2(): [10]
test2(nil): [10]
test2(true): [true]
test2(false): [false]
]]
```

The above approach breaks when the default value is Boolean `false`:

```lua
function test3(param)
  local default = false
  param = (param == nil and default) or param
  return param
end

--[[
test3(): [nil]
test3(nil): [nil]
test3(true): [true]
test3(false): [false]
]]
```

Interestingly, reversing the order of the conditional checks *does* allow Boolean `false` to be the default value, and is nominally more performant:

```lua
function test4(param)
  local default = false
  param = param or (param == nil and default)
  return param
end

--[[
test4(): [false]
test4(nil): [false]
test4(true): [true]
test4(false): [false]
]]
```

This approach works for reasons that seem counter-intuitive until further examination, upon which they are discovered to be kind of clever.

If you want default parameters for functions that *do* allow `nil` values to be passed, you'll need to do something even uglier, like using variadic parameters:

```lua
function test5(...)
  local argN = select('#', ...)
  local default = false
  local param = default
  if argN > 0 then
    local args = {...}
    param = args[1]
  end
  return param
end

--[[
test5(): [false]
test5(nil): [nil]
test5(true): [true]
test5(false): [false]
]]
```

Of course, variadic parameters completely thwart auto-completion and linting of function parameters in functions that use them.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that it's simplest and best way . in lua , variables by default equal with `nil`  . this means if we don't pass argument to lua functions ,the argument is exits but is `nil` and lua programmers uses of this lua attribute for set the default value .

also it's not a way for set default value but you can use following function

this function create a error is you don't pass values to arguments

```lua
function myFn(arg1 , arg2)
err = arg1 and arg2
if not err then error("argument") end
-- or
if not arg1 and arg2 then error("msg") end
```

**but it's not a good way and better is don't use of this function**

and in diagrams shows optional argument in [,arg]

```
function args(a1 [,a2])
-- some
end
function args ( a1 [,a2[,a3]])
-- some
end
```